# Windows 10 IoT Core - netsh http not found

Tags: http, ssl-certificate, windows-10-iot-core, netsh

Running

```
netsh http add sslcert hostnameport=xxx:443 appid= 'XXX' certhash=XXX certstorename=MY clientcertnegotiation=enable
```

I get

> The following command was not found: http add sslcert hostnameport=xxx:443 appid= 'XXX' certhash=XXX certstorename=MY clientcertnegotiation=enable

Seems that "http" doesn't exist in netsh of Windows 10 IoT Core.

Any workaround to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Windows IoT Core doest not support netsh http command. If you want to import the ssl certificate on Windows IoT Core. You can use following command:

1. Copy cert to C:\ on the device.
2. PS C:> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName -Credential Administrator
3. []: PS C:\Data\Users\Administrator\Documents> cd C:\
4. []: PS C:>Set-Location -Path cert:\LocalMachine\Root
5. []: PS Cert:\LocalMachine\Root> Import-Certificate -Filepath C:***.pem, if your certificate file is pfx, you can use Import-PfxCertificate command instead.

In addition, you can also import the certificate using programming. More information please see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/installing-certificates-into-iot-devices/).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, however it does not solve the possibility of binding a certificate to an ip. Windows IoT Core misses http.sys, so no way.